# Does disabling an interrupt A from interrupt B stops its execution without waiting for A to end?

Tags: c, embedded

I have a situation that when my interrupt is disabled, I believe that the code of the interrupt is not executed until the end. Is it possible that in the following code, variableA and variableB will ever different when is their turn to be printed?
At least, they may be different for some print (if the routine executes in the midst of the interrupt.) But when eventually things settle after the interrupt is disabled both variables should always have the same value.

myInterrupt is called at a fixed sample time, and someRoutine at another sample rate. An external condition is set at some point in the program.

```
int variableA = 0;
int variableB = 0;

void myInterrupt_A(void){
    variableA++;
    /*
     stuff
    */
    variableB++; // Will this instruction be executed if the interrupt is disabled before its execution?
}

void someRoutine(void){
 if some_condition
    Enable_myInterruptA();
 else
    Disable_myInterruptA();
 end
    /*
      stuff
    */
    printf("variableA= %d\n, variableB= %d\n", variableA, variableB)
}
```

What if "someRoutine" is, instead, an interrupt with higher priority?

Comment: If the interrupt function occurs during the preparation for calling `printf`, after a copy of one variable has been pushed onto the stack, but before a copy of the other variable has been pushed, then `printf` will output different values.

Comment: `printf` will never be executed in the midst of the interrupt, and the caller cannot disable the interrupt while it is being serviced, so cannot stop the interrupt handler from running to completion.

Comment: Re your edit, that would be foolish to call `printf` from an interrupt, *escpecially* a high priority one. And what would be the point of disabling a lower priority interrupt during the execution of a higher one?

Comment: But generally speaking, disabling an interrupt prevents it being triggered, but does not cripple it in mid flow.

Comment: what platform is this for?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, that answers my question. My original code has probably another issue somewhere else. I would not use a printf in an interrupt, it was just to indicate the point in the code where I want those variables to be evaluated (e.g. if(variableA!=variableB) ...)

Comment: I don't see why, a priori, it would be foolish to use printf in an interrupt. Strange, extreme, may be, but in many situations it can work perfectly.

Comment: @linuxfan for one thing `printf` is not rentrant, so it is too risky to use it in an interrupt. For another, it will hog a large amount of execution time, preventing lower priority interrupts from being serviced. An interrupt function should do the bare minimum for the job, if necessary passing flags and data to a higher level. I did also qualify my remark with "high priority interrupt". It is certainly foolish to ignore good practice just because you can sometimes "get away with it".

Comment: @WeatherVane I know the two things you said, and I agree. Still I would not say "foolish" so easily, that's all. I like embedded systems, especially the small ones, because the programmer has to have very deep knowledge which sometimes lets him do "strange" (not foolish) things.

Comment: While the question in the title is perhaps clear, the body text is entirely unclear. "*... the interrupt is not executed until the end.*" - the end of what!?   Simplify the question or express it with greater clarity and precision.  If your question is merely the title, just leave it at that - what more needs to be said?

Comment: To have any expectation of consistent behaviour within and across builds as other code which references the variables changes, you really should not forget to declare variableA/B as volatile.

Answer (score 1):

An interrupt is an event that causes an *interrupt service routine* (ISR) to run *to completion*.  Disabling the interrupt does not abort an in-progress ISR - it just prevents further interrupts.  The interrupt and the ISR are not the same thing; you are disabling the interrupt only.

If interrupt B were a higher priority and has preempted interrupt A, it may be possible I suppose to abort interrupt A by modifying the the stack so that returning from B does not cause a context switch to A but rather the the code preempted by A - but you really do not want to do that - it is horribly over complex and target specific.  If there is a problem with your interrupt handling there will almost certainly be a simpler solution (like good design!).